# animation working in iOS6, buggy in iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, animation, ios6

I have been trying to get to the bottom of this, and it escapes me. I have some buttons I want to ide when the user presses them. But instead of just hiding them, I want an animation. I am making them grow in size, before shrinking to a pinhead whilst also fading out.

I actually have this working as I desire in iOS6, but thought I would run it in a simulator for iOS5.1 and on my iPad1. Both of which make the button animation buggy. It grows, but then seems to explode into another dimension on the screen.

```
#pragma mark - animations
-(void)grow:(UIButton *)button {

    void (^makeItGrow)(void)= ^{
        button.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(button.transform,1.6, 1.6);
    };

    void (^whenFinished)(BOOL) =
    ^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [self shrink:button];
        }
    };

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:makeItGrow completion:whenFinished];

}

-(void)shrink:(UIButton *)button {
    void (^makeItShrink)(void)= ^{

        button.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(button.transform, 0.0, 0.0);
        button.alpha = 0.0;
    };

    void (^whenFinished)(BOOL) =
    ^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            //NSLog(@"shrink finished");
            [button setHidden:YES];
            [self resetButton:button];
        }
    };

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:makeItShrink completion:whenFinished];
}
```

I have slowed the animation down just so I could see it clearer. The first section does as it should, but the second section (the shrink) either splinters into the screen (you have to see it, it's does look kinda cool), or it simply continues to grow OUT of the screen! Certainly not what's desired.

And yes, I am still very much learning, I could probably take some pointers on my coding style :-)

Comment: Try setting the scale to a non-zero number like 0.1 and see if that helps.  I remember that a 0.0 scale caused some issues for me before.

Comment: You were spot in @borrrden thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set very low but not equal to zero scale factor.

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(button.transform, 0.0001, 0.0001);
```

Comment: I set it to 0.01. Worked like a charm. Borrrden did beat you to it, but you need some street cred. Here are some reps for you